# I used a plugin that hides wp-admin, but it hid wp-admin for admin too - how to revert back?

Tags: plugins

I used a plugin that hides wp-admin and does a lot of other things, but it hid wp-admin for admin-user too (due to some bad settings on my part probably) - how to revert back? I deleted the plugin's folder to get back to wp-admin, but as soon as I activate it, it again starts hiding admin-stuff. (It's retaining the settings it seems, because it doesn't hide admin-panel right away upon activation on fresh install. I had to alter the settings in wp-admin to make it hide wp-admin.)

Comment: Did you try asking the plugin author?

Comment: Sounds like the plugin saved some settings into your DB. You can manually edit your DB.

Answer (score 0):

I usually dont use plugins for this due to the fact its unstable.

I use this in my theme functions.php so you can always remove it if need be and it saves nothing to the DB.

This also leave open the admin ajax files if you need them for any theme functions like thickbox and a few others.

```
function erichamby_restrict_admin() {
if ( ! current_user_can('administrator')  && $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
}
}
  add_action( 'admin_init', 'erichamby_restrict_admin', 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you deleted the plugin folder ... so login to your website via FTP  and look for your .htaccess file

This probably was changed by the plugin and re-writes the URLs like `/wp-admin`

- Duplicate the file (to be safe)
- Open the file to edit it

Check / change the code back to:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```